# call javascript callback explicitly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions, one is for expanding tree view (i.e. ExpandAll()) and second one is for removing particular type of elements from that  tree view (i.e. RemoveAbElements()).

ExpandAll() method checks if there are child nodes under the selected node. If not then it retrieves the child elements by ajax call. So now I am calling these methods as follows :

```
function(){
    ExpandAll();

    RemoveAbElements();
}
```

Now my problem here is, there is a callback in ExpandAll() method and it gets called for each child node expanded (which is expected). Now here the callback gets called even after the execution of RemoveAbElements() method. I want to execute ExpandAll() method and all of its callbacks before RemoveAbElements() execution. I tried lots of things for this but none worked. please help.

Comment: Sounds like you've overcomplicated your design to me.  To me it sounds like your problem is at least one of your design decisions: lazy-loading your tree view (don't do this unless your data sets are enormous), asynchronous lazy-loading (if you want it to be asynchronous, then you need to put your post-processing into your onreadystatechange event handler), or requesting too much data which requires data to be filtered out from the response once you've received it (get the server to filter the data out if it's not going to be required).

Answer (score 1):

There could a be lot of ways you could be approaching.

One way could be, passing the **RemoveAbElements** itself to **ExpandAll**.

So you could be passing it as

```
ExpandAll(RemoveAbElements);
```

or, When you don't want to call RemoveElements, as :

```
ExpandAll();
```

And ExpandAll could be modified to accept the callback :

```
ExpandAll(callbackFunc) {

   //... Do Work Here

   if(callbackFunc) callbackFunc();
}
```

---

Or use [triggerhandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) & [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if there is a jquery object, as suggested by *slinky2000*.

Comment: Thanks loxxy for your reply, but ExpandAll() callback will be called multiple times. and I wanted to call RemoveAbElements() only once. Will it work like this?

Comment: you can leave that argument `null`, for cases when you dont want to call RemoveElements. I've updated my example...

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly you need to add a listener to EXpandAll()  and when it's finished everything call RemoveAbElements()

I would look at jquerys custom event triggering:

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
// Listen for finish
$('#tree').on('customFinishedEvent', function(event) {
    alert('finished');
});

// On finished loading and expanding
$("#tree").trigger('customFinishedEvent');
```